# for int of time (PHP)

Tags: php, math

the problem is there is a start (startHour, startMinute) and end (finishHour, finishMinute) field. The start field (startHour, startMinute) and the first input (hours) must have numbers up to 23, the next input (minutes) of the start must have numbers up to 59 but displayed every 5. So the first item works correctly. I move on to the next item, which is finishHour and finishMinute. Input first (hours) work fine. Input second (minutes) does not display the same as startMinute, ie having 59 numbers but displaying them every 5. I cannot detect this malicious error. Please help.

Here is the code I have:

```
         <div class="item">
          <div class="itemName">Rozpoczęcie:</div>
            <div class="itemInput">
                <select id="theme" name="startHour">
                    <?php for($i="0"; $i<="23"; $i++) { ?><option value="<?php echo sprintf('%02d', $i); ?>"><?php echo sprintf('%02d', $i); ?></option><?php } ?>
                </select>
                <span class="spacer">:</span>
                <select id="theme" name="startMinute">
                    <?php for($i="0"; $i<="59"; $i+=5) { ?><option value="<?php echo sprintf('%02d', $i); ?>"><?php echo sprintf('%02d', $i); ?></option><?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="itemName">Zakończenie:</div>
            <div class="itemInput">
                <select id="theme" name="finishHour">
                    <?php for($i="0"; $i<="23"; $i++) { ?><option value="<?php echo sprintf('%02d', $i); ?>"><?php echo sprintf('%02d', $i); ?></option><?php } ?>
                </select>
                <span class="spacer">:</span>
                <select id="theme" name="finishMinute">
                    <?php for($i="0"; $i<="59"; $i+=5) { ?><option value="<?php echo sprintf('%02d', $i); ?>"><?php echo sprintf('%02d', $i); ?></option><?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I mean to display every next 5 up to 59 which last would be 55

Comment: Well your code seems to be working fine, from 00, 05, 10 .. to 55?

Comment: Yeah I have same startMinute as finishMinute and it only displaying up do 23.. :/

Comment: Sir I can agree that it should display same because of same code but it doesn't. Could it be from server side?

Comment: I've run the code, both startHour and finishHour displays up to 23, while both startMinute and finishMinute displays to 55

Comment: Thank you for your help. Have tried to clear cache (didn't help). I have restarted my server and it did help!

Comment: Can you please extract a [mcve] and provide that here? It also helps you find the bug yourself.